# Which performs faster? vtable look-up with N derived types, or std::map look-up with N elements?

Tags: c++, performance, dictionary, vtable

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <ctime>

struct Base { virtual void foo() {} };
struct A : Base { void foo() {} };
struct B : Base { void foo() {} };
struct C : Base { void foo() {} };

A* protoA = new A;  B* protoB = new B;  C* protoC = new C;

enum Tag {a, b, c};

std::map<Tag, Base*> protoMap = { {a, protoA}, {b, protoB}, {c, protoC} };

void goo(Base* base) {base->foo();}

void hoo(Tag tag) {protoMap[tag]->foo();}

struct Timer {
    const std::clock_t begin;
    Timer() : begin (std::clock()) {}
    ~Timer() {
        const std::clock_t end = std::clock();
        std::cout << double (end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC << " seconds." << std::endl;
    };
};

int main() {
    const long N = 10000000;
    {
        Timer timer;
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
            goo(new C);  // using vtable
    }  // 0.445 seconds.
    {
        Timer timer;
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
            hoo(c);  // using map
    }  // 0.605 seconds.
    std::cin.get();
}
```

But my test only uses three derived classes, and I don't know how to define thousands of derived classes to benchmark properly.  Does anyone know the answer already so that I don't have to think of how to run better tests?

I'm in a situation where I can easily use a map, but to attempt to improve the performance with vtable look-up would require redesigning a lot of stuff I already have (add a new data member to a class, define a new constructor, implement a visitor pattern, etc...).

Comment: You're comparing apples with oranges; how does this "tag" approach help in a realistic polymorphic scenario?

Comment: @Oliver.  Because I'm in a situation where I can easily use a map, but to attempt to improve the performance with vtable look-up would require redesigning a lot of stuff I already have (add a new data member to a class, define a new constructor, implement a visitor pattern, etc...).

Comment: I take it that the vtable is faster and is the only proper way to go, despite the difficulty for me in my specific situation.

Comment: Pretty easy to create a thousand derived classes with a template using a non-type template parameter (e.g., an `int`). OTOH, vtable lookup isn't normally affected by the number of derived classes. An object has a vtable pointer, and that points directly to the vtable for its class. Other classes derived from the same base aren't involved at all.

Comment: Ok, I created many classes using a template.  The map performs a lot more slowly.

Comment: There is no need for any `new` statement in your code here. You can rewrite it without. This could make your real code faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without a doubt, the fastest way to go is the vtable.

**Experimentation:**

You have to run your benchmark in similar conditions.  It's not reasonable to allocate a new element for every call for the vtable benchmark, but not to allocate anything in the map approach.

I ran the test using a vtable approach using a pointer to an already allocated element. I got 16 ms for the vtable and 78 ms for the map approach.

If you want to go further and rally compare the 1000th derivates, you have to work with a recursive template.

**Explanation of the result:**

The vtable lookup generally uses a [fixed offset in the vtable](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/125-the-virtual-table/) of the object, and not a search. So even with 1000 derivations, you'll have a constant reaction time in O(1).

The map will need to do an expensive search operation on the key, which is O(log(n)).

**Additional remarks:**

The map implementation that you propose will not work in reallife, because you always call the member function for ONE SINGLE predetermined object: the one you stored in the map.  The virtual funtion will work with any object of the family.

Comment: Yes, thanks.  I ran my test using a template to create many classes.  vtable wins by far, and its time does not change with the number of derived classes.